# print javascript while loading

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
function myFunction(text, word){
   var pos1;
   do{
     pos1 = text.indexOf(word);
     if(pos1 !== -1){
        document.getElementById("id1").innerText = pos1;
     }
   }while(pos1 == -1);
}
myFunction(text, "sun");
myFynction(text, "rain");
myFynction(text, "gold");
myFynction(text, "hello");
myFynction(text, "laptop");
myFynction(text, "tree");
```

I get text from file_get_contents of a page. 
This page is continuously updating so, slowly, i will find those words through `myFunction`. What I want is to print those function meanwhile they finish

Comment: It is a very bad practice to scan the DOM or make changes to DOM elements within a loop. Additionally, `innerText` is not standard, `textContent` is.

Comment: sorry, I mean text

Comment: @ScottMarcus It will be used only from me. Anyway, what you suggest? a return?

Comment: It is really unclear what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: I take file_get_contents of a page that is continuously updating (I put this file_get_contents into a loop). For example after 5 minutes the page add "sun", then after 5 minutes add the word "rain" etc. etc. I don't want to wait 30 minutes to view pos of "sun". I want to view this pos immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know if it's possible to use javascript to continuously monitor the HTML that is being loaded into the current page.  It would require a few tests.  However this would be my approach.  (This function stops after finding one of the words in the array and displaying the pos)

```js
    var words = ['sun', 'rain', 'gold', 'HTML'];
    function myFunc() {
       var text = document.body.innerHTML;
       var pos1;
       for (var i=0; i < words.length; i++) {
         pos1 = text.indexOf(words[i]);
         if(pos1 !== -1){
            document.getElementById("id1").innerText = pos1;
            break;
         } 
       }
       if (pos1 === -1) {
         // wait 1 second, try again
         setTimeout(myFunc, 1000);
       }
    }
    
    myFunc();
```

```html
<div id='id1'></div>
```